# Setting Up Fish Shell Profile

Tags: terminal, fish

I am trying to set up my fish shell profile via  the **~/.config/fish/config.fish** command. I did not have a config.fish file and had to create my own after the install.

The main reason I want to update this profile is to show my current GitHub location in the terminal. I found the following settings online:

```
set -g -x fish_greeting ''
# fish git prompt
set __fish_git_prompt_showdirtystate 'yes'
set __fish_git_prompt_showstashstate 'yes'
set __fish_git_prompt_showupstream 'yes'
set __fish_git_prompt_color_branch yellow
# Status Chars
set __fish_git_prompt_char_dirtystate ' '
set __fish_git_prompt_char_stagedstate '→'
set __fish_git_prompt_char_stashstate '↩'
set __fish_git_prompt_char_upstream_ahead '↑'
set __fish_git_prompt_char_upstream_behind '↓'
function fish_prompt
printf ' '
set last_status $status
set_color $fish_color_cwd
printf '%s' (prompt_pwd)
set_color normal
printf '%s ' (__fish_git_prompt)
set_color normal
end
alias ls='ls -GFh'
alias fishprofile='nano ~/.config/fish/config.fish'
alias reboot='source ~/.config/fish/config.fish'
alias home='cd $HOME/Desktop'
function nvm
bass source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh ';' nvm $argv
end
cd ~/Desktop
```

After the code is pasted into the file path I am able to access the current GitHub terminal location, but as soon as the terminal has been relaunched this feature is gone. Any ideas on how to save this setting?

Comment: It sounds like you did not put that code into the config.fish file. What do you see with `cat ~/.config/fish/config.fish` ?

Comment: There's nothing in there with the cat command

Comment: Well that's your problem. Create the directory if it's missing, edit the file and add your desired contents.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Fish way of doing things, there is no need for a config.fish file.  What you show above is for compatibility reasons, and attempts to appease the config-file people.  Fish's way of doing things is to define functions (instead of aliases) inside of individual files located (usually) at ~/.config/fish/functions/ .  Variables are set and exported on the command-line, and are persistent.

See [this page](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_startup) for more information about my points.